# Silkscreen covering pads

Tags: pcb, manufacturing, silkscreen

Im prepparing my 1st pcb for manufacturing, and before i generate the gerbers i wanted to ask some things here fist,

What happens when i put a silk screen like this? a logo big enough to cover the solder joints will it actually cover them or it will the clads survive?
[image]

Answer (score 4):

It will "work" but the soldermask removal and missing ink will make your Logo look like crap. The vias will win every time, and you have A LOT of vias there. All of the PCB i've made from at least 3 different manufactures have all shown that part designators or logos are negatively affected by vias, so try to move the silkscreen around to avoid vias and through-hole pads if you can.

Answer (score 4):

Manufacturers will often remove the silk screen from pads but I wouldn't count on it.

It should generate a DRC error from any decent software.